# Compile Error on batch class to fetch fields from saveresult

Tags: dml, database, dmlexception, saveresult

I have below code to fetch field values from records of Database.Saveresult.

I am getting error as below.
**Error**

```
Expression of type Database.SaveResult has no member named Territory_Name__c
```

**Code**

```
for (Database.SaveResult sr : srList) {
        if (sr.isSuccess()) {
             Business_Plan_Approval_Process_Data_abv__c bpdata = new   Business_Plan_Approval_Process_Data_abv__c();
             bpdata.Business_Plan_Approval_Process_abv__c= sr.getId();  
             bpdata.Territory_abv__c= sr.Territory_Name__c;
             //Alstitem.External_ID_vod__c = actID+'-'+key;
             insbpdata.add(bpdata);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to rewrite your code like following

```
srList = Database.upsert( records, false );
for (Integer i = 0; i < srList.size(); i++ ) {
     Database.SaveResult sr = srList[i];
        if (sr.isSuccess()) {
             Business_Plan_Approval_Process_Data_abv__c bpdata = new   Business_Plan_Approval_Process_Data_abv__c();
             bpdata.Business_Plan_Approval_Process_abv__c= sr.getId();  
             bpdata.Territory_abv__c= records[i].Territory_Name__c;
             //Alstitem.External_ID_vod__c = actID+'-'+key;
             insbpdata.add(bpdata);
        }
    }
```